# Azure logic app Update Currency Exchange Rates parameter helps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, logic

I need to develop the Logic apps to update Currency Exchange Rate.
I do have the Api looks like that
https://api.int.org/rest/default/V1/currency/exchange-rate/?sourceCurrency=USD&destinationCurrency=EUR
The destination currency is dynamic; it would INR,EUR or any other currency.
I want to pass the destination currencies using the parameters.

I need help. How do I need to pass the parameters?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JduVU.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the parameter value in your parameters which enables you to add whenever it is required to build the flow.

[image]

Below is how the URI looks when reading from the parameters

```
https://api.int.org/rest/default/V1/currency/exchange-rate/?sourceCurrency=USD&destinationCurrency=@{parameters('destinationCurrency')}
```

[image]